# Personally identifying data in Django Request

Tags: django, logging, django-request

I was working on a Django project which had no user data logging.

Then I added IP Address and User Agent logging for posts.

What other personally identifying do I get other than IP Address and User Agent in a Django request in the view.

I don't want to log too much. The above two should be enough. But I just want to know if there is any other good information to log about the user.

Comment: username when they log in?

Comment: @dukebody I already do that. I meant additional data like from Anon users. Like the two I mentioned.